# Cloudwatch : cannot see my host in CWAgent(custom namespace) metric

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to push the memory usage of my ec2 instance to cloudwatch. I have the cloudwatch agent running in the ec2 instance. I have the config file on AWS ssm. this is how it looks

```
{
    "agent": {
        "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
        "run_as_user": "root"
    },
    "logs": {
        "logs_collected": {
            "files": {
                "collect_list": [
                    {
                        "file_path": "/var/log/my-service/*.log",
                        "log_group_name": "my-service",
                        "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "metrics": {
        "append_dimensions": {
            "AutoScalingGroupName": "${aws:AutoScalingGroupName}",
            "ImageId": "${aws:ImageId}",
            "InstanceId": "${aws:InstanceId}",
            "InstanceType": "${aws:InstanceType}"
        },
        "metrics_collected": {
            "disk": {
                "measurement": [
                    "used_percent"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                "resources": [
                    "*"
                ]
            },
            "mem": {
                "measurement": [
                    "mem_used_percent"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60
            },
            "statsd": {
                "metrics_aggregation_interval": 10,
                "metrics_collection_interval": 10,
                "service_address": ":8125"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am starting cloudwatch agent with this command

> sudo
> /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/./amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a
> fetch-config -m ec2 -c ssm:AmazonCloudWatch-linux -s

The logs are being pushed from the locations mentioned in the config, but I do not see the memory metric being pushed. If I understand correctly I should see the ip address of my instance under CWAgent--> host under Metrics. Unfortunately, I do not see this.

I tried checking the cloudwatch agent logs under /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/logs
/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.log

I do not see any logs which says, it pushed or trying to push any metric.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're under the right namespace? You need to click `All Metrics` from the left pane, and then go to: `All > CWAgent > InstanceId`

Should look like this once you've set up your CloudWatch agent to send logs on the EC2 instance:

[image]

You may be under another namespace like `All > EC2 >  Per-Instance Metrics`

This is assuming you have set up the cloud watch agent appropriately using the [launch wizard](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/create-cloudwatch-agent-configuration-file-wizard.html).

Answer (score -1):

I believe that do will you see the *instance name* not IP address